# Overloading PHP die() function

Tags: php, overloading

I need to overload the die() function. For example, I want to pass an extra parameter to die() function which is when set to true, it sends an email to me that something abnormal happened to the site.
Can you please help me out!!!

Thanks to all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't oveload built in function, but you can write a wrapper:

```
function die_with_grace($message, $send_email=false) {
    if ($send_email) {
        // send email here
    }
    die($message);
}

mysql_query('...') or die_with_grace('Error in query', true);
```

Answer (score 5):

> Hi all ... I need to overload the die() function.

No, you don't.

You could use [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) or [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to run some code on a PHP error.

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to check through the documentation and experiment to see which shutdown scenarios these functions will be triggered for.

Comment: Note that you can also trigger these errors yourself by using trigger_error.

Comment: [`register_shutdown_function` will execute whenever the script ends, regardless of an error or not.](http://codepad.org/zeTdC3YT)

Comment: @Gordon: Yes, I know. That doesn't mean it can't be used. You can set a flag when your script ends "normally", affecting the behaviour of the shutdown function. I'm not saying it's optimal, but it _is_ a possible approach.

Comment: @Gordon: [Here you go](http://codepad.org/IHRxbDq7) - This is the very same approach as the first comment on [the documentation for `register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php). (Again, I'd like to re-iterate that I'm not suggesting this is the _best_ approach!)

Comment: thanks. interesting approach. I didnt thought of using flag markers with a reference. I agree to "not the best approach", but interesting :)

Answer (score 4):

PHP doesn't allow that. Just use your own function:

```
<?php
function ddie($email=false){
  if ($email) doemail();
  die();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont want to do that. `die()` is not an error handler. It simply exits the script. What you are likely looking for is

- [`error_log` — Send an error message somewhere](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

**Example:**

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    error_log('DB troubles', 1, 'admin@example.com');
    die;
}
```

The alternative to that would to use [`trigger_error`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) in combination with [`set_error_handler`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Answer (score 1):

Even though `die()` and `exit()` look like functions, they really are just built-in features that PHP calls "language constructs." So even if there were a simple way to override functions, it wouldn't work. (It *is* possible to replace functions via third party extensions, but that's not what you really want here anyway.)

You may want to look into [trigger_error()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) or using exceptions (e.g., `throw new EmailException()`). Both of those could be trapped and optionally used to send an email.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create your own custom die(); function? Just create custom_die(); and have it send you an e-mail then die();.

Note that you'll likely get occasional blips where you'll get a ton of e-mails due to simple server hiccups.